# I want to compile my code to 32 bit systems and have the following make file, how do I make it right?

Tags: c, makefile, x86, 32-bit, osdev

So, I got this Makefile from a git repository and it compiles the source code that came with this correctly. The project is for an Operating System from scratch. This Makefile is for a 64-bit OS tutorial. I'm currently learning about 32-bit operating systems and I don't want to jump into the long mode for now. My project compiles correctly with this makefile but it never loads the kernel into memory. I think I should change the `CCFLAGS = -ggdb -c -ffreestanding -target x86_64-none-elf` to some other flags. How do I go about this. I already tried install `i386-elf-gcc` using brew but it's giving me a lot of errors. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

```
CC = clang
GDB = gdb 

LD = ld.lld
ASM = nasm

INC = -Iinc/
SRC = $(shell find . -type f -name "*.c")
ASM_SRC = $(shell find . -type f -name "*.asm")

# CRITICAL: assembly must be linked first
OBJ = ${ASM_SRC:.asm=.o} ${SRC:.c=.o} 

CCFLAGS = -ggdb -c -ffreestanding -target x86_64-none-elf
LDFLAGS = -Ttext 0x8200
LDFLAGS_BIN = ${LDFLAGS} --oformat binary
LDFLAGS_ELF = ${LDFLAGS} --oformat binary --entry main
ASFLAGS = -f elf64

all: kernel kernel.elf

kernel: ${OBJ}
    @${LD} -o $@ ${LDFLAGS_BIN} $^

kernel.elf: ${OBJ}
    @${LD} -o $@ ${LDFLAGS_ELF} $^

%.o: %.c
    @${CC} ${CCFLAGS} ${INC} -o $@ $^

%.o: %.asm
    @${ASM} $< ${ASFLAGS} -o $@

clean:
    @rm -f kernel kernel.elf *.o **/*.o
```

Comment: Most probably you need to set another target, "i386" or "i586" instead of "x86_64".

Comment: clang -m32 will give you a generic 32bit variant; -march=i486 will target 486.   You can discover which arch's are available with -march=junk (ie. something that won't match one).